# I am trying to put each 3 characters ( not spaces ) .into an array, but I'm getting these errors:

Tags: c

```
test2.c: In function 'main':
test2.c:28:3: warning: format '%s' expects a matching 'char *' argument [-Wformat=]
   while( fscanf(fp, "%s%s%s" , str)){
   ^
test2.c:28:3: warning: format '%s' expects a matching 'char *' argument [-Wformat=]
```

and Segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ARRAY_LIMIT 4
#define MAX 100

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {   
    char* array[MAX];
    char str[ARRAY_LIMIT];  
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf( "Wrong number of arguments.");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (fp == 0){
        printf ("failed to open input.txt\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int j = 0;
    while( fscanf(fp, "%s%s%s" , str)){
      array[j] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*3); 
      strcpy(array[j], str); 
        j++;
    }
        printf( "%s\n", array[0]); 
        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: [sample code](https://ideone.com/qfB5I7)

Comment: you are missing arguments to your fscanf. Since you have 3 '%s' it need two more char * as to port those 3 strings. You only have one 'str' http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fscanf/. On top of that if you are trying to get char, I think you should use '%c' and use offset from str to put strings, it str, str+1, str+2.

Answer (score 0):

To read one string of length three, use `"%3s"`, not `"%s%s%s"`. 
The segfault is coming from an issue with your EOF check. You should have this as your loop condition:

`fscanf(fp, "%3s", str) != EOF`

You're also not allocating large enough strings. They should be size `sizeof(char)*4`, since there's a null terminating byte (credit to BLUEPIXY in comments).

Comment: but i want all the three characters in one array?

Comment: Thank you the error is gone I'm still getting Segmentation fault after compling : ./test2 test.txt

Comment: `sizeof(char)*3` --> `sizeof(char)*4`

Comment: fscanf gets each three characters and goes to the next three characters. but im trying to get character 0 1 2, 1 2 3, 2 3 4, and so on until the character in empty. Any suggestions?